# ¿Cómo puedo subir archivos pdf, word o powerpoint desde Firebase kotlin?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

Quiero crear un botón para subir archivos a firebase pero que esos archivos puedan ser de power point, word o pdf.

De antemano gracias

Comment: Buenas, te recomiendo que intentes realizarlo y luego nos cuentes que problemas tienes con el código, StackOverflow no es un sitio donde hacemos la tarea de los demas sino que respondemos dudas que tengas con tu código, saludos

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, es importante agregar lo que hayas tratado o investigado, revisa por favor [ask] y edita tu pregunta. No olvides realizar el [tour] para conocer su funcionamiento.

Answer (score -1):

Supongo que ya sabes como obtener el documento, pero sino, se selecciona de la siguiente manera:

```
private val selectImageFromGalleryResult =
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument()) { uri: Uri? ->
        uri ?: return@registerForActivityResult

        uploadFile(uri)
    }
```

Si estas usando ContentResolve,  despues de que obtengas el archivo, necesitas crear un archivo temporal dentro de la carpeta raiz de tu app para poder subirlo.
Despues llamas a los metodos de Firebase para subir el archivo y le pasas el archivo temporal. Cuando se haya cargado lo borras.

```
fun uploadFile(uri: Uri) {
    val file = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
    val tempFile = File.createTempFile("temp_image", ".${File(uri.path!!).extension}")

    ByteArrayInputStream(file?.readBytes()).use { input ->
        tempFile.outputStream().use { output ->
            input.copyTo(output)
        }
    }

    storageRef.reference.child("test").putFile(tempFile.toUri())
        .addOnSuccessListener { tempFile.delete() }
        .addOnFailureListener { it.printStackTrace() }
}
```

Para abrir el seleccionador de archivos, llamas:

```
selectImageFromGalleryResult.launch(arrayOf("application/*"))
```

Mis metodos se llaman asi porque los modifique de uno que tengo para hacer este codigo.

Comment: Aunque tu respuesta es completa, evita responder a preguntas en donde el autor de la misma no haya demostrado sus intentos para llegar a una solución. Lee [answer], sobre todo la sección _Contesta preguntas **bien formadas**_.